# Nesting and looping with less incremental

Tags: css, less

I am not sure how to implement this in less, not sure where to start.

The purpose is to increment the padding by a variable(15px in this example) to a depth (increment variable). Is this possible in less?

```
ul {
  li{
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  ul {
    li{
      padding-left: 45px;
    }
    ul {
      li{
        padding-left: 60px;
      }
      ul {
        li{
          padding-left: 75px;
        }
        ul {
          li{
            padding-left: 90px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Loops](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature), e.g.:

```
.make-nested-lists(5);

.make-nested-lists(@n, @i: 0) when (@i < @n) {
    ul li {
        padding-left: (30px + 15 * @i);
        .make-nested-lists(@n, (@i + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Though I have to admit that CSS like `ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li ...` looks at least strange, there's something really wrong with your approach. (So my vote goes to @Fabrizio Calderan answer).

Answer (score 4):

this should be enough

```
ul {
  li{
    padding-left: 30px; /* base value */

    li{
      padding-left: 15px;  /* increment */
    }
  }
}
```

the first list-item has `30px` of left padding, then since `<li>`'s are nested they inherit the padding of ancestor items. So the child has 30 + 15 = `45px` of left padding, the grandchild `60px` and so on.

Example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uGxHy/

---

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I was trying to do this in less, and allow it go go multiple levels deep without having to manually enter the calculated values.